# Returning T[] (where T is Byte[]) to Byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-6

I have a Java JUnit 4 test and a generic class which creates a generic array. When I create a method to return this generic array I get an error message upon returning it. It works if I return an ArrayList (where T is Byte by class instantiation) to an ArrayList.

Why is it that the array appears to be instantiated and usable (tested on more complex classes) yet I can't return a reference to that array?

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.waikato.assignment.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte;
at com.waikato.testing.TestJava.test(TestJava.java:20)
```

**Class:**

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    T[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TestClass() {
        array = (T[]) new Object[32];
    }

    public T[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public boolean doThing() {
        T[] t = array;

        return t == array && t != null;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class TestJava {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestClass<Byte> t = new TestClass<Byte>();
        Byte[] b = t.getArray(); // Crash caused

        assertTrue(t.doThing()); // Works when above line is removed.
        assertTrue(b.length != 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "generic" array can be constructed via reflection:

```
T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(Byte.class, 32)
```

Replace `Byte.class` by a reference to the desired class. In other words:

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    T[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TestClass(Class<T> type) {
        array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, 32);
    }

    public T[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public boolean doThing() {
        T[] t = array;

        return t == array && t != null;
    }
}
```

You can verify this as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass<Byte> test = new TestClass<Byte>(Byte.class);
    // No ClassCastException here
    Byte[] array = test.getArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

Due to type erasure, you cannot solve this problem without resorting to a `Class<?>` object as a constructor argument.

Comment: But fixing the class you will spoil the genericness of the method, won't you? That way you will have `ClassCastException` for every type, but `Byte`

Comment: There is no generic method in the OP's `TestClass`. `TestClass` itself is generic...

Comment: This is on track to where I want to go (edited Q to hopefully better reflect that). I'm after a generic array and have come across the new Object[x] method and Array.newInstance() method. It's disappointing to see there is no way to use Array.newInstance() without passing the Class<T> object.

Comment: @SimonCampbell: No there isn't. Java Arrays use covariance. If you want to have a `T[]` array, you will need to supply the type of `T` in the form of a `Class<T>`. Since `<T>` itself is erased, the generics information is no longer available at runtime. [Boris mentioned a trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10330471/521799), that works in some special cases. In this case, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

```
array = (T[]) new TestClass[32];
```

That does not look like a `Byte[]` to me and the compiler should warn you about the generic cast being ignored at runtime.

This is the generic solution

```
TestClass(Class<T> tclass){
   //create an array for the generic type
   array = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(tclass,32);
}


TestClass<Byte> bTest = new TestClass(Byte.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to find out Actual Type arguments for a Generic Typed Class.

I just changed constructor like this for Main class.

```
public class TestClass<T> {
T[] array;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public TestClass() {
    Class<T> objClass;
    objClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // Found the type paramenter
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance( objClass, 32);
}

public T[] getArray() {
    return array;
}

public boolean doThing() {
    T[] t = array;

    return t == array && t != null;
} }
```

And the Test method..

```
@Test
public void test() {
    TestClass<Byte> t = new TestClass<Byte>(){}; // Added {}
    Byte[] b = t.getArray(); 

    Assert.assertTrue(t.doThing()); 
    Assert.assertTrue(b.length != 0);
}
```

Comment: I just escaped passing a Class Type argument to the constructor.

Comment: Interesting... But then, you need a subclass per `<T>` type, potentially even per instance if subclasses are anonymous... And you must never forget to subclass `TestClass`... Maybe make `TestClass` `abstract`?

Comment: Exactly.. making it an abstract class avoids the problem right at the compile time.
But it depends on author of the class and his requirements.. whether to make it abstract or just pass a Class Type..

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
public TestClass() {
    array = (T[]) new TestClass[32];
}
```

This contradicts the title of your question, i.e. "where T is Byte" as T is initialised into TestClass.

One idea is to change array into a List<T>.

Comment: new T[] does not work in java, the generic type does not exist at runtime.

Comment: @josefx yes, my apologies. updating answer